# Harris corner detector at different rotations

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, corner-detection

I am using the opencv implementation of Harris Corner detection in python. My question is regarding the behaviour shown in the gif below - as the image is rotated the corners stop being detected (at various rotations). The full code:

```
import cv2

image_path = 'image1.jpg'

original_image = cv2.imread(image_path)

def play(video, name='video', wait=60, key='q'):
    for f in video:
        cv2.imshow(name, f)
        if cv2.waitKey(wait) == ord(key):
            return

def rotate(image, theta, point=(0,0)):
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((point[1], point[0]), theta, 1)
    return cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (image.shape[1], image.shape[0]))

def rotate_detect(image):
    for theta in range(0, 360):
        img = rotate(image, theta, (original_image.shape[0] / 2, original_image.shape[1] / 2))

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray,9,13,0.04)

        #result is dilated for marking the corners, not important
        dst = cv2.dilate(dst,None)

        # Threshold for an optimal value, it may vary depending on the image.
        threshold = 0.005
        img[dst>threshold*dst.max()]=[0,0,255]
        yield img

play(rotate_detect(original_image), wait=60)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

based on [this](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_features_harris/py_features_harris.html).

[image]

The image used can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkbFD.jpg). It is perhaps not so clear from the gif (more clear if you run the code), but the corners are detected when the grid lines are horizontal/vertical.

If the `blocksize` parameter is increased, we can get the desired behaviour (to detect corners at all rotations).

> Question - How can the behaviour shown in the gif be explained?

Comment: All I can assume from your results is that the implementation in OpenCV is bad. This would not be the first such example I’ve seen. OpenCV cuts a lot of corners to be fast, and so it sometimes produces poor results.

Comment: Try cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack() which use the Shi-Tomasi corner detector. See https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_shi_tomasi/py_shi_tomasi.html. You may have to adjust the corner threshold for the rotation angle. Also see http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~laganier/publications/coin.pdf for a morphology based approach.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I have compared the results between OpenCV and Scikit-image and I don't think the answer is so simple.

Comment: @Catree, I think it is. In your answer you say it uses a box filter. That is not rotation invariant by definition. Your SciKit implementation is a bit better, but I’d use Gaussian gradients for true rotation invariance. And the method used to rotate the image is important too, not sure which is used by OP nor your answer.

Comment: @CrisLuengo What do you mean by Gaussian gradients? Sobel + Gaussian filtering? Bilinear interpolation is used but there will be some degradation. SciKit follows (more?) strictly the method but I do not see a better stability. I see better corner extraction accuracy though. I meant, the OpenCV implementation has been designed this way rather than badly implemented. It is not easy to implement the algorithm with good accuracy and with good performance. Too easy to trash the OpenCV library. There are some badly implemented algorithms in OpenCV but not many contributions that help to fix that.

Comment: @Catree: See [this blog post of mine](https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/22) for an explanation of Gaussian gradient estimation. The Gabor filter is an approximation that is not very isotropic. // OpenCV cuts a lot of corners to be faster. Some of these corners (like using box filters) are IMO a really bad choice that make the results unsatisfactory in many cases. Producing poor results can’t have been a design decision, I think the implementer didn’t realize how bad this particular choice was.

Comment: @Catree: I've posted an answer showing rotational invariance when using a correct implementation that prioritizes precision.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for the pointers. This is definitely interesting. I will try to experiment more with the algorithm and the different implementations. I am still a little bit puzzled. Compared to your implementation, the Scikit implementation does not produce good results. I am using [`corner_peaks()`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.16.x/api/skimage.feature.html#skimage.feature.corner_peaks) to select the corners from the response map. Maybe the parameters I used are not optimal. Also, I want to test if using image in `uint8` vs `float32` makes a difference or not with Scikit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Updated:

Use [`goodFeaturesToTrack()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga1d6bb77486c8f92d79c8793ad995d541) instead of using the manual code to retrieve the corners from the Harris response map.

You will have to adapt the `blockSize` and `qualityLevel` to your use case if you want to have correct results with OpenCV.

Left is DIPlib, right is OpenCV results.

[image]

---

DIPlib code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import diplib as dip
import numpy as np
import imageio
import os

img = imageio.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkbFD.jpg')
img = dip.Image(img)
img.SetColorSpace('rgb')
img = dip.ColorSpaceManager.Convert(img,'gray')

animation = []
times = []

for angle in range(0,360):
    img_rot = dip.Rotation2D(img, np.radians(angle), '3-cubic', 'add zeros')
    img_rot = img_rot.Pad(np.maximum(img.Sizes(), img_rot.Sizes()))
    img_rot.Crop(img.Sizes())

    start = timer()
    harris = dip.HarrisCornerDetector(img_rot, sigmas=[3.0])
    end = timer()
    times.append(end - start)
    harris *= dip.Maxima(harris, connectivity=2)
    harris = dip.Dilation(harris > 1, 5)
    harris = dip.Overlay(img_rot, harris)
    harris.Convert('UINT8')
    animation.append(harris)

print('Mean computation time: {:f}s'.format(np.mean(times)))
print('Median computation time: {:f}s'.format(np.median(times)))
print('Std computation time: {:f}s'.format(np.std(times)))

save_folder = 'DIPlib'
if not os.path.exists(save_folder):
    os.mkdir(save_folder)
for idx, img in enumerate(animation):
    imageio.imsave('{}/Harris_DIPlib_{:03d}.png'.format(save_folder, idx), img)
```

OpenCV code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import division
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import argparse
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import os

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Test Harris corners rotation invariance.')
parser.add_argument('--input', default='', type=str, help='Input image path')
parser.add_argument('--save', default=False, type=bool, help='Save results')
parser.add_argument('--maxCorners', default=500, type=int, help='Maximum number of corners')
parser.add_argument('--qualityLevel', default=0.03, type=float, help='Minimal accepted quality of image corners')
parser.add_argument('--minDistance', default=11, type=int, help='Minimum possible Euclidean distance between the returned corners')
parser.add_argument('--blockSize', default=11, type=int, help='Size of an average block for computing a derivative covariation matrix over each pixel neighborhood')
args = parser.parse_args()

harris_params = dict(maxCorners = args.maxCorners,
                     qualityLevel = args.qualityLevel,
                     minDistance = args.minDistance,
                     blockSize = args.blockSize,
                     useHarrisDetector = True)
print('harris_params:\n', harris_params)

image_path = 'hkbFD.jpg'
original_image = cv.imread(image_path)

def play(video, name='video', wait=60, key='q'):
    idx = 0
    directory = 'OpenCV'
    if args.save and not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)

    times = []
    for f, elapsed_time in video:
        times.append(elapsed_time)
        cv.imshow(name, f)

        if args.save:
            filename = directory + '/Harris_OpenCV_%03d.png' % idx
            cv.imwrite(filename, f)
            idx += 1

        if cv.waitKey(wait) == ord(key):
            return

    print('Mean computation time: {:f}s'.format(np.mean(times)))
    print('Median computation time: {:f}s'.format(np.median(times)))
    print('Std computation time: {:f}s'.format(np.std(times)))

def rotate(image, theta, point=(0,0)):
    M = cv.getRotationMatrix2D((point[1], point[0]), theta, 1)
    return cv.warpAffine(image, M, (image.shape[1], image.shape[0]))

def rotate_detect(image):
    for theta in range(0, 360):
        img = rotate(image, -theta, (original_image.shape[0] / 2, original_image.shape[1] / 2))

        gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        start = timer()
        harris_cv = cv.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray, **harris_params)
        elapsed_time = timer() - start

        for c in harris_cv:
            cv.circle(img, (int(c[0,0]), int(c[0,1])), 8, (0,0,255))

        yield (img, elapsed_time)

play(rotate_detect(original_image), wait=60)
```

---

## Old:

#### Description of the algorithm

[This paper](https://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2018/229/) analyses the implementation of the Harris corner detector.

> @article{ipol.2018.229,
>
> ```
> title   = {{An Analysis and Implementation of the Harris Corner Detector}},
> author  = {Sánchez, Javier and Monzón, Nelson and Salgado, Agustín},
> journal = {{Image Processing On Line}},
> volume  = {8},
> pages   = {305--328},
> year    = {2018},
> doi     = {10.5201/ipol.2018.229},
> ```
>
> }

The algorithm is the following:

[image]

Step 1 is not included in the [original paper](http://www.bmva.org/bmvc/1988/avc-88-023.pdf).

---

#### OpenCV Harris corner detection implementation

- with [some specific conditions](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3d14dd4e3953aa7b7e2ab3a388ca7bf08fe99d99/modules/imgproc/src/corner.cpp#L649-L651), Intel IPP library is used to extract the Harris corner
- [`ippiHarrisCorner_8u32f_C1R()` documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/ipp-dev-reference-harriscorner)
- otherwise, the OpenCV implementation is roughly:

  - Computes image gradient with Sobel
  - Computes products of the gradients
  - Box filter
  - Computes the corner response

---

#### Scikit-image corner detection implementation

- documentation is [here](https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.16.x/api/skimage.feature.html#skimage.feature.corner_harris)
- code is [here](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/434a0cfa15962d78923b30451b278be182b1a421/skimage/feature/corner.py#L447)

The code is straightforward:

```
    Axx, Axy, Ayy = structure_tensor(image, sigma)

    # determinant
    detA = Axx * Ayy - Axy ** 2
    # trace
    traceA = Axx + Ayy

    if method == 'k':
        response = detA - k * traceA ** 2
    else:
        response = 2 * detA / (traceA + eps)

    return response
```

with `structure_tensor()`:

```
    image = _prepare_grayscale_input_2D(image)

    imx, imy = _compute_derivatives(image, mode=mode, cval=cval)

    # structure tensore
    Axx = ndi.gaussian_filter(imx * imx, sigma, mode=mode, cval=cval)
    Axy = ndi.gaussian_filter(imx * imy, sigma, mode=mode, cval=cval)
    Ayy = ndi.gaussian_filter(imy * imy, sigma, mode=mode, cval=cval)

    return Axx, Axy, Ayy
```

and `_compute_derivatives()`:

```
    imy = ndi.sobel(image, axis=0, mode=mode, cval=cval)
    imx = ndi.sobel(image, axis=1, mode=mode, cval=cval)

    return imx, imy
```

---

#### OpenVX Harris corner detection specifications

It can be found [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenVX/specs/1.3/html/OpenVX_Specification_1_3.html#group_vision_function_harris).

From these specifications, vendors can ship custom implementation optimized for their platform. For instance, the [ARM compute library](https://arm-software.github.io/ComputeLibrary/latest/namespacearm__compute_1_1test_1_1validation_1_1reference.xhtml#adc64cfa88bef3958e1603bfca23db47a).

---

#### Comparison between OpenCV and Scikit-image.

- Versions used:

```
OpenCV: 4.2.0-dev
Numpy: 1.18.1
scikit-image: 0.16.2
```

- Harris parameter `k=0.04`
- OpenCV Harris function parameters that are modified, default values for the experiments are: `blockSize=3` and `ksize=1`
- Scikit-image Harris function parameter that is modified, default value for the experiment: `sigma=1`
- Left: OpenCV results; Right: Scikit-image results

**Sudoku image**

- default parameters:

[image]

- OpenCV: `blockSize=7`, `apertureSize=3` ; Scikit-image: `sigma=5`:

[image]

Repeatability rate can be computed, but not sure that my code is totally correct:

[image]

Distance threshold is 5.

From my experiments, it looks like Scikit-image yields better corner location accuracy.

**Blox image**

- default parameters:

[image]

- OpenCV: `blockSize=3`, `apertureSize=3` ; Scikit-image: `sigma=3`:

[image]

**OP Sudoku image**

- default parameters:

[image]

- OpenCV: `blockSize=7`, `apertureSize=3` ; Scikit-image: `sigma=7`:

[image]

**Calibrator image**

- default parameters:

[image]

---

Code is [here](https://gist.github.com/catree/d9b5c9ac6635acc70ffb26b2f65aad96).

Answer (score 5):

This answer is just to show that a correct implementation of the Harris corner detector should be perfectly rotation invariant.

As the animated image shows, there are a few detections (in the background and within tight clusters) that appear or disappear at random angles. These are caused by imperfect interpolation and unavoidable floating-point rounding errors. But most detections are consistent at all angles. [*NOTE: the GIF was too large to upload to SO, I'm showing to frames here, feel free to run the script to see the animation.*]

[image: 0 degrees] [image: 20 degrees]

The implementation used is the one in [DIPlib](https://diplib.org). It uses Gaussian gradients to compute the derivatives, and Gaussian low-pass filtering for the local averaging. [The Gaussian is a perfectly isotropic filter](https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/22). The implementation uses single-precision floating-point operations throughout, to minimize rounding errors. You can find it [here](https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/blob/1918cbcb89feac292689d02ecc2ab99326771851/src/detection/corners.cpp#L29). DIPlib is aimed at precise quantification, and therefore attempts to avoid unnecessary numerical errors. [*Disclosure: I'm an author.*]

```py
import diplib as dip
import numpy as np
import imageio

img = imageio.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkbFD.jpg')
img = dip.Image(img)
img.SetColorSpace('rgb')
img = dip.ColorSpaceManager.Convert(img,'gray')

animation = []

for angle in range(0,180,4):
   img_rot = dip.Rotation2D(img, angle/180*3.14159, '3-cubic', 'add zeros')
   img_rot = img_rot.Pad(np.maximum(img.Sizes(), img_rot.Sizes()))
   img_rot.Crop(img.Sizes())
   harris = dip.HarrisCornerDetector(img_rot, sigmas=[3.0])
   harris *= dip.Maxima(harris, connectivity=2)
   harris = dip.Dilation(harris > 1, 5)
   harris = dip.Overlay(img_rot, harris)
   harris.Convert('UINT8')
   animation.append(harris)

imageio.mimsave('./so.gif', animation, fps=4) # This file is too large for SO

imageio.imsave('./so_00.png', animation[0]) # Frame at 0 degrees
imageio.imsave('./so_20.png', animation[5]) # Frame at 20 degrees
```

Comment: I used [https://ezgif.com/video-to-gif](https://ezgif.com/video-to-gif) to compress the gif and [https://imgur.com/](https://imgur.com/) to upload it.

Comment: I have the following error when running your code: `img = dip.ColorSpaceManager.Convert(img,'gray')
RuntimeError: Image's number of tensor elements and color space are inconsistent` But `print('img:', img.shape)` after `imread` gives `img: (480, 640, 3)`.

Comment: Probably something like this is missing: `color = dip.ColorSpaceManager.Convert(img, 'RGB')
img = dip.ColorSpaceManager.Convert(color,'gray')`

Comment: How to convert from `PyDIP.PyDIP_bin.Image` to Numpy type? I would like to convert `img_rot` into a Numpy array. This way I can test the code with other libraries.

Comment: @Catree: I've updated the code, it was missing the explicit assignment of color space to the image before using `ColorSpaceManager`. You can use a `dip.Image` object anywhere where you'd use a NumPy array. To explicitly convert to a NumPy array use `np.array(img_rot)` (no data is copied).

Comment: Thanks, it works now. Why the saved images are "whiter" than the original images when using DIPlib?

Comment: @Catree: I guess you overlay the detections on the original color image in the OpenCV case, and on the gray-scale image in the DIPlib case.

Comment: Indeed, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand the Harris algorithm first. A corner is a point whose local neighbourhood stands in two dominant and different edge directions. In other words, a corner can be interpreted as the junction of two edges, where an edge is a sudden change in image brightness.

In order to find the edges, Harris algorithm take the image and apply a Gaussian filter to smooth out any noise. Then it **applies Sobel operator to find the x and y gradient values** for every pixel in the grayscale image. For each pixel `p` in the grayscale image, consider a `3×3` window around it and compute the corner strength function. Call this its **Harris** value. The it finds all pixels that exceed a certain threshold and are the local maxima within a certain window. Finally for each pixel that meets the criteria in 5, compute a feature descriptor.

As you can see, Harris algorithm highly relies on **X and Y gradients** in the image. Is you can see in the GIF image, when your image is horizontal or vertical, the grid table generates many hight gradient values.

Comment: The magnitude of the gradient signal for different rotated corners should not differ?

Comment: There is no reason for the Harris feature to not be rotation invariant, except for a poor implementation.